# Adding PhoneGap onto Xcode Project Without Using XCode

Tags: xcode, cordova, github, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I was running Windows 7 desktop only. My next project is about a social network app created from my fellow programmer. Check out his XCode project at GitHUB repository right [here](https://github.com/kerwintang/BoyKuripot).

He asked me to convert this iOS compatibile into an Android compatible app so that his created app can now run on Android.

I discovered [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/), an online app converter that requires to copy the URL of a  GitHub repository and in order to make the conversion successful, I have to implement some kind of PhoneGap engine (Cordova.jar, HTML5 [index.html], and a simple Javascript).

It's preferred to do this in Xcode, but Xcode requires Mac OS X. Is there another way, if it's possible, to add a PhoneGap engine without Xcode?

Here's the reason why I have to update and added the PhoneGap without using XCode since I'm running on Windows 7 before taking a second attempt to convert it using PhoneGap Build. Here's the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap allows a developer to build a native application using HTML5 - essentially, the web application is packaged into a native application container that simply renders a webview then loads the index.html from the web app into that webview and passes control to the web app.

There is no conversion of a native iOS application into an Android application.

You do not need Xcode to package PhoneGap apps using PhoneGap Build - all you need is the web content for your app. When you initiate the build process, the Build service packages your web app into native apps for Android, BlackBerry, iOS, webOS, Windows Phone.

You can learn a lot about PhoneGap in my book PhoneGap Essentials - www.phonegapessentials.com.